# Group by with lists in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with a Dataframe looking like this:

[image]

It contains "ClusterLabels" (0-44) and I want to group the "Document" col by the ClusterLabel value. I want These lists from "Document" to be combined in one list per Cluster. (duplicate words sould be kept)

Tryed the ".groupby" argument but it gives the error "sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found".

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like :

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Document" : [["a","b","c","d"],["a","d"],["a","b"],["c","d"],["d"]],
                   "ClusterLabel": [0,0,0,1,1]})

df
```

[image]

```
df.groupby("ClusterLabel").sum()
```

[image]

Comment: @jezrael it worked for me but how would you solve it?

Comment: @Nicson  Added 2 solutions for solve non `sum` solution for `concatenate lists`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use sum to concatenate lists. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice.

Better is use list comprehension with flatten lists:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('ClusterLabel')['Document']
         .agg(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y])
         .reset_index())
```

Or flatten in `itertools.chain`:

```
from  itertools import chain

df1 = (df.groupby('ClusterLabel')['Document']
         .agg(lambda x: list(chain(*x)))
         .reset_index())
```